# angular http get by id not working

Tags: angular

I am trying to follow the Tour of Heroes tutorial. Instead of `getHeroes()` and `getHero(id)`, I have `getCustomers()` and `getCustomer(id)`. The code is the same as in the tutorial. The `getCustomers` is working but `getCustomer()` is not working. I have verified that my Web API controller is returning a JSON file for `getCustomer()` just like with `getCustomers()`. The only difference is that my `id` parameter is a `string` instead of `number`.

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

### customer.service.ts

```
getCustomers(): Observable<Customer[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.customerUrl)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

getCustomer(id: string): Observable<Customer> {
    const url = `${this.customerUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get(url)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

### customer-detail.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params
        .switchMap((params: Params) => this.customerService.getCustomer(params['id']))
        .subscribe((customer: Customer) => this.customer = customer);
}
```

Comment: what is console error?

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to set the `name` attribute the html form `input` elements.

Comment: is that solves your problem ??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it seems to be solved.